# Find PDF on $[0,6]$ such that $P([1,3]) = 0.5$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-distributions

> Find a probability density function $f$ on $[0,6] \subset \mathbb{R}$, such that $\mathbb{P}([1,3]) = 0.5$

That is we need to find an $f$, such that $\int_{[0,6]} f(x)dx = 1$ and $\int_{1}^{3} f(x)dx = 0.5$. I already tried functions of the form $f(x) = -cx$ and $-cx^2$ just by plugging it into the integral for $[1,3]$ and then solving for $c$. I was hoping for this to magically work out, but in both cases the integral on $[0,6]$ didn't equal $1$. What is a good way to solve a problem like this? Is there a general strategy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply choose a piecewise constant function $f$. Let the value of $f$ on $[1, 3]$ be $a$ and the value on $[0, 1) \cup (3, 6]$ be $b$. Now you can determine the value of $a$ and $b$ with the two equations you have.

Answer (score 1):

Try
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac14,&1\le x\le 3\\\frac12,&4\le x\le5\\0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases} $$